# What happened when python reallocate object and how can I notice it?

Tags: python, memory, realloc

Thank you for visiting.

At first, I was curious about what happened when append object to array infinitely.

So, I tried.
`append 3 to array until id of array changed`

My idea is like below.

Someday, python should reallocate array to the other place(in heap segment). Then the Virtual Memory address will be also changed. According to the note in cpython source,

> [python/bltinmodule.c-1201th line] 
>  This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.(CPython uses the object's memory address.)

This is my test code

```py
arr = [3]
prev_id = id(arr[0])
print('arr_id:',hex(id(arr)))
print('prev_id:',hex(prev_id))
i = 1
import time
start = time.time()
while prev_id == id(arr[0]):
    arr.append(3)
    if(i % 10000000 == 0):
        tmp = time.time()
        print(hex(id(arr)), hex(id(arr[-1])), i, tmp-start)
        start = tmp
    i += 1

print(id(arr))
```

the result is...

```
prev_id: 0x7f9d00c9f5a0
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 10000000 3.284541130065918
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 20000000 3.3981776237487793
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 30000000 3.1428868770599365
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 40000000 3.3757195472717285
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 50000000 3.1835339069366455
...
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 840000000 3.0633106231689453
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 850000000 3.1029069423675537
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 860000000 3.124239921569824
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 870000000 3.0969555377960205
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 880000000 3.0810909271240234
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 890000000 3.090634346008301
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 900000000 3.079714298248291
0x7f9d00c9f5a0 0x7f9d00c9f5a0 910000000 3.051016092300415
(the program infinitely append '3' to the array until run out of memory.)
```

[image: [edited]graph with third and fourth column (x: 10,000,000*append, y: time(s))]

graph with third and fourth column (x: 10,000,000*append, y: time(s))

[image: [edited]graph with third and fourth column (x: 10,000,000*append, y: time(s))]

comparison 'append(3)' and 'append(1234567)'

[image: log message in colab. It seems that something is reallocated]

log message in colab. It seems that something is reallocated

### [Three figures were edited at 2021.04.23]

by the graph, we can notice that the graph is periodically pointed. I think it's because python reallocate.

> 1. Is my guess right?

Plus, I actually want to get the virtual memory address of array. May be this(`0x7f9d00c9f5a0`) is it.

> 2. Then (though, array is reallocated) why the id of array is same?

How can I get the virtual memory address of array after it is reallocated?

Comment: NOTHING ever changes the ID of an existing object.  Anything that grows in size (and therefore eventually needs memory reallocation), such as a list, will necessarily have the growing part as a separate block of memory, pointed to by the fixed-size block that the ID refers to.  There's no way to determine the address of that separate block from pure Python.

Comment: Thank you so much jasonharper!
By the way, can you explain deeply about "list will necessarily have the growing part as a separate block of memory, pointed to by the fixed-size block that the ID refers to."?

Comment: The Python list object itself cannot move in memory (because that would invalidate all existing references to the list).  But the list data has to be able to move in memory (because there generally wouldn't be any room to expand the data when the list grows).  This is not the only conceivable solution, but having the list data in a separate memory block is certainly the simplest one.  There's only one reference to the list data (in the list object itself), so it can easily be updated when a reallocation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

CPython is just being smart.

You are appending 3 which is actually stored by default in CPython in a memory location to make it faster to look it up. I forget how many values are stored by default but you can verify this by checking:

```py
In [45]: a = [12]

In [46]: print(hex(id(12)), hex(id(a[-1])))  # Will be the same
0x7ffab6401800 0x7ffab6401800

In [47]: a = [1234]

In [48]: print(hex(id(1234)), hex(id(a[-1])))  # Will be different
0x18f41c9a490 0x18f41d88e10
```

If you wanted to check the range of these, you can do this:

```py
In [66]: def find_min_max():
    ...:     min_val = max_val = None
    ...:     for i in range(-1000, 1000):
    ...:         if i < 0 and min_val is None:
    ...:             if id(int(str(i))) == id(i):
    ...:                 min_val = i
    ...:         if i > 0 and max_val is None:
    ...:             if id(int(str(i))) != id(i):
    ...:                 max_val = i-1
    ...:     return min_val, max_val

In [67]: find_min_max()
Out[67]: (-5, 256)
```

So in this case on my system, and probably yours, `[-5, 256]` are going to have the same ID. Since you're constantly appending 3, you're just basically appending the same unique memory address, which is most likely making it so your array isn't needing to be reallocated. If you want to force it, try appending something like `257`, or something outside of the range of values that are stored.

EDIT:
The `id` will not change, however. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

Because the object is still alive it will retain the original `id`. So there isn't a way to see the relocation happening from the Python side.

Edit #2:

Okay.... so you might be able to do this. But it's complicated. Technically you still cannot do this through `id`, but you might be able to do this through adding your own type by building a custom type in C. The code for Python lists can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). Specifically what you're interested in is `list_resize`. I don't have the time to test this unfortunately. But what you could do is either change code there, which seems like a pain since you'd have to compile and have your own version of Python, or create a custom type that essentially wraps a Python list.

To do this you'll need to know C and include `"python.h"`, but you should be able to create a new custom `PyListObject` and basically duplicate the existing functionality but also add another member variable to show the memory address of the list.

For instance:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

is the default.

Add your own like this:

````c
```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;
    PyObject *base_address;

    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
````

and then during your new `list_resize`:

```c
static int
list_resize(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t newsize)
{
    PyObject **items;
    size_t new_allocated, num_allocated_bytes;
    Py_ssize_t allocated = self->allocated;

    if (allocated >= newsize && newsize >= (allocated >> 1)) {
        assert(self->ob_item != NULL || newsize == 0);
        Py_SET_SIZE(self, newsize);
        return 0;
    }

    new_allocated = ((size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + 6) & ~(size_t)3;
   
    if (newsize - Py_SIZE(self) > (Py_ssize_t)(new_allocated - newsize))
        new_allocated = ((size_t)newsize + 3) & ~(size_t)3;

    if (newsize == 0)
        new_allocated = 0;
    num_allocated_bytes = new_allocated * sizeof(PyObject *);
    
    /* PREVIOUS IMPLEMENTATION */
    // items = (PyObject **)PyMem_Realloc(self->ob_item, num_allocated_bytes);
    /* NEW IMPLEMENTATION*/
    void* addr = PyMem_Realloc(self->ob_item, num_allocated_bytes);
    self->base_address = (PyObject*)addr;
    items = (PyObject**)addr;

    if (items == NULL) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        return -1;
    }
    self->ob_item = items;
    Py_SET_SIZE(self, newsize);
    self->allocated = new_allocated;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chrispresso :)

I used value '3' intentionally. At first I appended 'i'(in my code). But, I changed it to 3 to remove side effect of allocating numbers which are bigger than 256.

Also, I think appending the same unique memory address can't be a reason to 'your array isn't needing to be reallocated'. 

Am I wrong?

Comment: Plus, I did another Experiment with appending '1234567'. You can check the graph and log message in my Question body(I edited it).

In extra experiment, id isn't changed as you mentioned. But, as you can see in the graph there are some spots and the log message said that there is a large alloc.

Isn't it consequence of relocation of array? ( maybe because of cache size? )

Let's share our thoughts a little bit more:)



Thank you so much!!
cheers X

Comment: `id` will never change though even if the underlying memory is re-alloced. If it changed the anything in Python that held a reference to it would need to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Chrispreesso. I'll think about it a little bit more. You gave me a power to go through:)

Comment: @Youseop I updated to a way that you can technically get the memory address of the Python object, but it requires a lot of work ;)

Comment: I was just checking cPython. It will take some time I guess, but if I get some results(or something), I will let you know.